# Get the item which date is closest to now

Tags: c#, list, datetime

In my database I have a list of items with the following property:

```
public System.DateTime CARD_OF_DAY_DATE_CREATED { get; set; }
```

I need to get the item which `CARD_OF_DAY_DATE_CREATED` is the closest to `DateTime.Now` using c#. I could do massive for/foreach loops, but I was wondering if there was a good, efficient way to do it with anything?

**Note:** The `CARD_OF_DAY_DATE_CREATED` field needs only to be checked **forward**, meaning that checking if the `CARD_OF_DAY_DATE_CREATED` is yesterday would be non-relevant because those items won't be in the list.

Comment: It depends on the collection, without any assumption you can only do a _massive_ for/foreach. Things are different, for example, if it's an ordered list.

Comment: you could go for a stored procedure maybe...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
var item = list
    .Where(i => i.CARD_OF_DAY_DATE_CREATED > DateTime.Now)
    .OrderBy(i => i.CARD_OF_DAY_DATE_CREATED)
    .First();
```

Comment: Yeah, nice! I think that'll do just fine :) I will try it out!

Comment: Wouldn't `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` be better than `Take(1)`?

Comment: Right but just one note: unless data comes from a database LINQ just hides a foreach with a nice syntax. OP must be aware of this because he asked "*...could do massive for/foreach loops, but I was wondering if there was a good, **efficient**...*"

Comment: Well the syntax is one thing but if you have anything to offer @Adriano I'd be glad to see it

Comment: @HerveS to keep a nice syntax (then performance penalty of enumerations) I would use `list.Where(x => x.CARD_OF_DAY_DATE_CREATED > DateTime.Now).Min(x => x.CARD_OF_DAY_DATE_CREATED)`. You do not need to **sort** if you're just interested with minimum value...

Comment: It was slightly unclear whether the data was coming from a database or not until I decided base my answer as if it was EF or something. Because in that case we are talking about IQueryable and a translation to SQL at enumeration which would make this query ideal.
If not, this would suck :)

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg of course this works (we don't have more informations). I just wouldn't **sort** if unneeded :)

Comment: @Adriano using `Min` returns the minimum date value and not the _item_ having the minimum date value.

Comment: Well, both are alright. I could use the date and the value. But I'm glad because I had the occasion to learn both ways :)

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg yes but a second linear search (using DateTime as predicate) is faster than a sort (even a good algorithm will enumerate through items more times). Of course if date does not comes from a database!

Comment: Well, if you are in learning mood, please read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx 
`CARD_OF_DAY_DATE_CREATED` is not considered a standard in naming. `CardOfDayDateCreated` would be more accepted :)